# How can I use power automate (flow) to get details from many MS Forms (all based off the same template) and put the responses in to a SharePoint list?

Tags: power-automate, ms-forms

I have a number of forms I send out for a business group to approve / reject.

They are all based on a template (yes/no and why)

How can I use power automate (flow) to get the  details from these MS Forms and put the responses in to a SharePoint list  ( I can get the details for a single form no issue ) just want to know how to get it work for multiple forms?

Is this even possible?

hmmm... I have had a look through flow, but cant see how to feed in different forms to a single flow?

Comment: You need to have a single flow for each form but if you have common logic, feed the payload from each of those flows into a single flow that does the work. Make sense?

Comment: Might be an option to look into the https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/ endpoint and an HTTP type of action. I have seen people using this to retrieve stuff in bulk. Have a look at this thread: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/api-to-access-ms-forms/m-p/1463830/page/2